# DynamoDB: How to specify version attribute through schema

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, optimistic-locking

```
@DynamoDBVersionAttribute      
private long version;
```

We are not using annotations in our project. So for every model, we have a schema definition. I am not sure how to specify a version attribute field through schema definition.

```
StaticTableSchema.builder(User.class)
            .newItemSupplier(User::new)
            .addAttribute(String.class, a -> a.name("userName")
                    .getter(User::getUserName)
                    .setter(User::setUserName)
                    .tags(secondaryPartitionKey("userName-index"))) // GSI
            .addAttribute(Integer.class, a -> a.name("id")
                    .getter(User::getId)
                    .setter(User::setId)
                    .tags(primaryPartitionKey())) // Primary Key
            /*.addAttribute(Long.class, a -> a.name("version")
                    .getter(User::getVersion)
                    .setter(User::setVersion)
                    .tags(VersionRecordAttributeTags.attributeTagFor(null))
                    )*/
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the AWS docs for optimistic locking (e.g., [C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.VersionSupport.html) and [Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.VersionSupport.html)) this a feature of the mapping SDK, not a feature of DynamoDB or the table-attribute itself. If you look at the [CreateTable API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html), there is no way to add an "automatic" versioning column. Looking at other DDB table APIs, there's no way to add it after the fact (like with [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTimeToLive.html)).

In order to accomplish this, you'll have to encode the use of [Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)  to effect a conditional update, setting an expectation for the pre-update value of the version attribute.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187030/85269) has more information with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag "VersionedRecordExtension.AttributeTags.versionAttribute())"
See an example below:

```
.addAttribute(Long.class, a -> a.name("version")
        .getter(Foo::getVersion)
        .setter(Foo::setVersion)
        .tags(VersionedRecordExtension.AttributeTags.versionAttribute()))
```